# Displaying geoprocessing service results in ArcGIS Online Map

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service

I am implementing a Python script that filters features in a feature service. For this I used the following lines of code:

```
import arcpy
 
# URL with service, where clause and field parameter
baseURL= "https://services2.arcgis.com/50d5wsDbZicDslDY/arcgis/rest/services/Gewerbefl%C3%A4chenkatalog/FeatureServer/1/query"
where = '1=1'
fields ='Ort, PLZ, Gesamtgroesse'
    
#The above variables construct the query
query = "?where={}&outFields={}&returnGeometry=true&f=json".format(where, fields)
fsURL = baseURL + query
 
fs = arcpy.FeatureSet()
fs.load(fsURL)
 
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fs, r"c:\test\test.gdb\result")
```

I want to publish this script as a geoprocessing service on an ArcGIS for Server 10.3 and use the service in ArcGIS Online.

What do I have to change in the script so that the result of this query is shown in a web map in ArcGIS Online or in ArcMap?

I have heard that I could use `arcpy.SetParameter()` to create an output but in my tests this idea failed every time.

I know that I could use the "Filter Widget" in ArcGIS Online, but this widget is currently not very flexible regarding optional filterparameters and so my idea was to build my own tool.